# In measure theoretic probability, why is $P_X = P \circ X^{-1}$ the same as the CDF $F_X$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, proof-explanation, expected-value

Suppose that we are given a random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$.

Then the expectation is given by,

$$
E(X) = \int X(w) dP(w)
$$

I am trying to make sense of the "change of variable" formula,

$$
E(X) = \int_\Omega X(w) dP(w) = \int_\mathbb{R} x dP_X(x) = \int_\mathbb{R}x dF_X(x)
$$

where $P_X$ is the distribution of $X$ and $F_X(x)$ is the CDF of $X$.

I am stuck at various points:

---

To start, let $x = X(w) \Leftrightarrow X^{-1}(x) = w$,

Then $P(w) = P(X^{-1}(x)) = (P \circ X^{-1})(x)$

Then define $P_X := P \circ X^{-1}$.

But then we claim that $P_X = F_X$.

Recall that $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x) = P(\{w \in \Omega | X(w) \leq x)$.

But $P \circ X^{-1}(x) =  P(w) \neq F_X(x)$          $\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $ (?)

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: $X^{-1}(x)=w$ is a strange construct.

Comment: $X^{-1}(x)=\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)=x\}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ok that actually helps alot. But how do I deal with the inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by assuming $X$ is a simple function and show the equalities in this case.  This case just amounts to $P_X$ having only point-masses and $F_X$ having finitely many jumps (and otherwise constant), so you can evaluate all the integrals directly.

Then assume $X \geq 0$ and approximate $X$ from below by simple functions (use the monotone convergence theorem).

Finally write $X$ as the difference of two non-negative random variables and, assuming at least one is integrable, conclude the equations hold whenever they make sense.  (The only case not dealt with by this treatment is one in which the integrals don't exist)

Answer (score -2):

> Suppose that we are given a random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$.
>
> Then the expectation is given by,
>
> $$ E(X) = \int X(\omega) dP(\omega)$$

No, it is:

$$\mathsf E(X)=\int_\Omega X(\omega)~\mathsf P(\mathrm d\omega)$$

> I am trying to make sense of the "change of variable" formula,

$$
\mathsf E(X) = \int_\Omega X(\omega)~\mathsf P(\mathrm d\omega) = \int_\mathbb{R} x ~\mathsf P_X(\mathrm dx) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}x~\dfrac{\mathrm dF_X(x)}{\mathrm d x}\mathrm d x
$$

Comment: I don't see the difference. The formula is defined in Durrett's probability textbook.

Comment: I would argue $\int_\Omega X(\omega) \,dP(\omega)$ better represents the measure-theoretic interpretation of the integral (in which case $d\omega$ might make no sense in the analogy), but it's really just notation: not something to argue about objectively.

Comment: $\mathrm dP(\omega)$ vs. $P(\mathrm d\omega)$ is just a matter of notational preference and is of course the same.